# How to resolve Errno 13 Permission Denied

Tags: python, glob, errno, shutil

I have researched the similarly asked questions without prevail.  I am trying to os.walk() a file tree copying a set of files to each directory. Individual files seem to copy ok (1st iteration atleast), but an error is thrown (IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'S:/NoahFolder\.images') while trying to copy a folder (.images) and its contents? I have full permissions to this folder (I believe).

What gives?

```
import os
import shutil
import glob

dir_src = r'S:/NoahFolder/.*'
dir_dst = r'E:/Easements/Lynn'
src_files = glob.glob(dir_src)
print src_files

for path,dirname,files in os.walk(dir_dst):
    for item in src_files:
        print path
        print item

        shutil.copy(item, path)
```

Comment: @CodyBouche these look like windows file paths, and telling someone to blindly `chmod 777` is bad advice.

Comment: @Noah create a smaller example. Can you use `shutil.copy` to copy a single item out of the problematic directory?

Comment: If you are getting a "Permission denied" error then it is reasonably safe to conclude that you don't "have full permissions to this folder".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shutil.copy` will only copy files, not directories. Consider using [`shutil.copytree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) instead, that's what it was designed for.

Comment: Your answer seems to hit close. I have tested using try/expect and can successfully place files outside of subfolder however no luck with subfolder? When run without comment the shutil.copytree call throws this error: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists. 
`for path,dirname,files in os.walk(dir_dst):
        for item in src_files:
            try:
              shutil.copy(item, path)
            except:
                print item
                print path
              #shutil.copytree(item, path)`

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to copy files that `copytree` has already created for you, by continuing to walk down directories you have already processed?

Answer (score 1):

This implementation of copytree seemed to get it done! Thanks for the input @ holdenweb

```
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

for path,dirname,files in os.walk(dir_dst):

    for item in src_files:
        try:
          shutil.copy(item, path)
        except:
            print item
            print path
            copy_tree(dir_src, path)
```